# Assembly Language - Escape Sequence Handling Subroutine

Tags: assembly, escaping

I was tasked with writing a subroutine in NASM x86 Assembly which handles escape sequences. I've finally gotten it to the point where it doesn't segfault, however it doesn't do the conversion for lower case characters. For instance if I type Hello\nWorld, it prints HellonWorld, where n should be replaced by 10 for newline. I'm using a lookup table for the conversion. I'm chopping some pieces out of the code that need to be rewritten but here's what I have to just test for the lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bugs:

```
        mov     ecx, buf                ; Arg 2: address of buffer
        mov     edx, BUFLEN             ; Arg 3: buffer length
        mov     [ecx + edx], byte 0     ; null terminate the read buffer
        ; out of bounds, overwriting newstr first byte
        ; you should do "dec edx" ahead of write (dec edx == sub edx,1)
        ; when not sure about last index, imagine buffer of size 1 (ofs 0)
```

---

```
lowercase:
        cmp     ax, 'a'                  ; is it a?
        ; you loaded "bl" with value, and it's 8bit, not 16bit
        ; so you should do cmp bl,'a' (and next cmp is wrong too)
```

---

```
        mov     ecx, [esi]               ; move the char to ecx to index
; no, nope. Not at all. First the "esi" already points beyond "\n"
; you already did inc esi twice (L1_top: and handle_ESC: )
; and mov ecx,[esi] will fetch 4 bytes (dword), it will load ecx with 'Worl'
; you want to do movzx ecx,bl (zero extending byte "n" in bl to dword in ecx)
; or and ebx,0xFF (masking out the higher 3 bytes to zero) and work with ebx
        mov     ebx, mappings            ; point to the mappings array
        sub     ecx, 97                  ; convert the lower case letter to decimal
; I would suggest to write it as: sub ecx,'a' - to keep human intent readable
        mov     ax, [ebx + ecx]          ; indexed addressing done here
; loading two bytes, while your table is byte-sized, plus your index is *1
; if you would create word-sized table
; you would have to do "shl ecx,1" (index*2) after sub 'a'
; but mov al,[ebx+ecx] should be enough
```

---

Then after `call handle_ESC` you write ax into newstr, and inc edi twice.
This is invalid logic.

For `"\0123"` (octal) you want to write only single byte, but advance esi by 5.
For `"\\"` you want to write single byte and advance by 2 (? C-like escape).
For `"\n"` you want to write single byte and advance by 2
etc

So the newstr can be significantly shorter then original str, and the result of handle_ESC always single byte I think, you should then store only `al` (converted value), and advance `edi` only once.

You should rethink your code logic to handle all requested cases correctly.

And to output the correct length of newstr (or pad it at end with `' '` space character to make the rest of buffer "invisible", then you can actually print whole BUFLEN).

---

This is just what I found by a quick look, I didn't tried to compile it or run, use your debugger.

---

Edit after question edit (version 2 of source) (BTW, that's again SO policy, to edit question after being answered, but I'm fine with that in this particular case .. maybe you should have just extended the original to show edited parts):

```
    mov     ebx, mappings            ; point to the mappings array
    movzx   ecx, bl                  ; move the char into ecx for indexing
```

Do you realize `bl` is part `ebx`? So you overwrite the char value with least significant byte of `mappings` address, losing the char value. The remedy in this case is simple, `ecx` is already available ahead of `mov     ebx, mappings`, so you can move the `movzx` ahead of it.

(I didn't check rest of the changes)

About debugger: you should probably put breakpoint after the input syscall and "run" it. Also check if there's some setting which console/terminal should be used as input, in linux debuggers often opens whole new terminal for I/O (I'm using "edb" for tiny asm programs, works well for me, and reminds me of classic turbo debugger from Borland from 1990+ era, and the new terminal window is used there).

But actually I would suggest something different, comment out STDIN reading syscall, and instead put there hard-coded setup of variables, like `mov [buf],'A\n!'` `mov eax,4` `...etc...` to simulate syscall output values. Then you can focus on stepping in debugger without checking the terminal window (except for output).

And you can prepare several versions of inputs and switch trough them by commenting them out. Later you will realize it's even easier to create reasonable API to simply call your function upon some provided buffer, receiving result into other buffer, and running it several times with providing different source data pointers. So you will be able to debug several test inputs at single go, plus create function with simple easy-to-use interface.

Comment: So I'm just a bit confused by the part about buf / buflen. I did change it so that I just dec edx, but are you saying that line should be before mov [ecx + edx], byte 0? I fixed up my lowercase label and I'll post my latest iteration. However no matter what lower case letter I put in, it adds the lowercase letter r to the write buffer.

Comment: @swingonaspiral `%define BUFLEN 1` `buffer: resb BUFLEN` `var1 resb 1` - allocates one byte at address `buffer+0` and one byte at address `var1+0`, which is equal to `buffer+1`. So with 1 byte long buffer the `mov ebx,buffer` `mov esi,BUFLEN` `mov [ebx+esi], byte 0` is already writing beyond the buffer at `buffer+1` address, into `var1` memory. It's like C++: `array[size-1] = last_value;`, and `array[size] = out_of_bounds;`. You are doing `buf[BUFLEN] = 0;`: +1 offset beyond the `buf`. Moving the `--size` ahead of storing 0 terminator will both fix the write, and prepare length for syscall.

Comment: Okay I get it now, thanks! Any suggestions on how to get this thing to store the converted char correctly when it's a lowercase letter? It's stuck just writing the letter r.

Comment: @swingonaspiral And unless you missed it, the most important part of the answer is **"use your debugger"**. As some people here like to point out, programming in assembler without debugger is like assembling a robot being blindfolded (actually *I* believe Assembly w/o debugger is harder). It may be a bit tedious to find some working for you and learn how to use it, but it's absolutely essential to write anything functional. Just running the executable and see proper output doesn't mean much, could have been accident for particular input values (like your memory overwrite probably works).

Comment: In fact it did work when it probably should not have, as you said. I'm looking at a list of suggested debugging commands. When I set a breakpoint before running, it doesn't allow me to input anything though. I'm trying to look for some kind of command that will let me do this but I'm also not entirely sure what to search.

Comment: @swingonaspiral updated the answer as well. I'm pretty sure you will be now on the track, once you figure out debugger, looks to me like you hit most of the common problems already and got it right.

Comment: That's embarrassing, I didn't think to set the breakpoint after the spot where it asks for input. Thank you for all your help, you are awesome!